# Deluge on Arch ARM

Tags: archlinux, software-installation

I have deluge installed and the web ui running.  It can add torrents, find peers, find DHT peers, open ports via UPnP: great!  What it can't do is download anything.  I get no errors, but no connections to peers or progress either. From the console:

```
ID: 28f171b2d06b4bd82c2f42026bfb24e4fd324598
State: Downloading Down Speed: 0.0 KiB/s Up Speed: 0.0 KiB/s
Seeds: 0 (18353) Peers: 48 (11006) Availability: 0.00
Size: 0.0 KiB/0.0 KiB Ratio: -1.000
Seed time: 0 days 00:00:00 Active: 0 days 00:11:59
Tracker status: openbittorrent.com: Announce OK
Progress: 0.00% [~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~]
```

Comment: looks like it might be a magnet link bug for deluge on all platforms. http://forum.deluge-torrent.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=41681&p=176351&hilit=torrent+has+no+metadata#p176351

Comment: I suggest trying `transmission-cli` if you want a command line torrent client. It's more lightweight and arguably more stable than deluge.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by BHP in the comments, it is/was a link bug, according to [the forum post](http://forum.deluge-torrent.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=41681&p=176351&hilit=torrent+has+no+metadata#p176351).

Given that the current version in the repository is 1.3.3, it is most likely solved. Please tell us if the problem persists.